# Description of Krishna

Tags: bhagavata-purana

Can you give some description of Krishna from Srimad Bhagavatam? I have tried to search a lot but nothing is satisfying. I can't grasp the true essence.

Comment: By description do you mean dhyanamantra or character assessment ?

Comment: Just character and physical assessment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the physical description of Lord Krishna from Bhagavatam

> O son of the king of the cowherds, Your transcendental body is dark
> blue like a new cloud, Your garment is brilliant like lightning, and
> the beauty of Your face is enhanced by Your gunja earrings and the
> peacock feather on Your head. Wearing garlands of various forest
> flowers and leaves, and equipped with a herding stick, a buffalo horn
> and a flute, You stand beautifully with a morsel of food in Your
> hand.(SB 10.14.1)
>
> The Supreme Personality of Godhead, Krsna, is the reservoir of all
> beauty. All beautiful things emanate from Him, and His personal form
> is so attractive that it steals the eyes away from all other objects,
> which then seem devoid of beauty in comparison to Him. When Lord Krsna
> was on the earth, He attracted the eyes of all people. When Krsna
> spoke, His words attracted the minds of all who remembered them. By
> seeing the footsteps of Lord Krsna, people became attracted to Him,
> and thus they wanted to offer their bodily activities to the Lord as
> His followers. In this way Krsna very easily spread His glories, which
> are sung throughout the world by the most sublime and essential Vedic
> verses. Lord Krsna considered that simply by hearing and chanting
> those glories, conditioned souls born in the future would cross beyond
> the darkness of ignorance. Being satisfied with this arrangement, He
> left for His desired destination.(SB 11.1.6–7)
>
> When a person realizes You, he no longer cares about his good and bad
> fortune arising from past pious and sinful acts, since it is You alone
> who control this good and bad fortune. Such a realized devotee also
> disregards what ordinary living beings say about him. Every day he
> fills his ears with Your glories and thus You become his ultimate
> salvation (SB10.87.40)